# Modifying H323 tcp packet using linux router

Tags: linux, perl, tcp, packet

I have a Linux router on which I use CONFIG_IP_NF_QUEUE, iptables userland and Perl module `IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue` to examine H323 - H.225 packets and pass or drop then. I have need to not only accept or drop the packet but to modify it, to be more specific I would like to change the IP address of the MCU (in the packet) returned from the H323 gatekeeper to the client.

This would require me to examine the TCP packet body and change the IP address in the packet body. Anyone know how can I accomplish this? Is there any open source layer 7 router capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In the old days I've used "ip masquerade" to do something similar to what you are describing.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/supported-client-software.html

But the best solution is to place a gatekeeper as a proxy. In that way you are not fooling the protocol, you are actually remaking the call.

I would look for gnugk routed mode here:

http://www.gnugk.org/h323-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have already got the IP packet, which from your statement you have succeeded in doing so, I don't see the problem to change the IP address of the packet before passing it on.

Just do some bits manipulation to change the IP address in IP header (also update the IP checksum). Also note that you have to update the TCP header checksum as its calculation involves a pseudo-header that includes IP addresses.

Just read [RFC 791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt) and [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) would give you an idea on how to do this. It's pretty straightforward.